# How to efficiently store node structures and calculate depth in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet of different components that have several sub components that are represented by a node structure. The script I am working on calculates the levels of these components, but it does not take into account that a it's sub components can appear in different trees in the same excel sheet without having the sub components defined each time.

This is the test sheet I have.
[image]

This is how the node strucutre looks like. A1's sub components is only defined in one of the trees via the traversal. I only care about the highest level of each product since it will make it easier for the BOM to count the total amount of items. So the output should be:

A0:1
A1:3
A2:4
A3:5
B0:1
B1:1
B2:4

[image]

This approach does not work with the given node structure, it only works if each sub component is listen each instance it's parent is listed.

```
Sub BOM()
    
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim lvl As Long, children As New Collection, child
    Dim endRow As String
    
    endRow = ":B" & CStr(Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng = Range("A2" & endRow)
    
    rng.Columns(3).ClearContents
    lvl = 1
    'collect all the "root" parents
    For Each c In rng.Columns(1).Cells
        If IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng.Columns(2), 0)) Then
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = lvl
            children.Add Array(c.Offset(0, 1).Value, lvl) 
        End If
    Next c
    

    Do While children.Count > 0
        child = children(1)(0) 
        lvl = children(1)(1)   
        children.Remove 1      
        For Each c In rng.Columns(1).Cells
            If c.Value = child And Len(c.Offset(0, 2).Value) = 0 Then
                c.Offset(0, 2).Value = lvl + 1
                children.Add Array(c.Offset(0, 1).Value, lvl + 1) 
            End If
        Next c
    Loop

End Sub
```

The real data sheet is more than 20 000 lines and the only idea I have now is saving A1 and checking when it gets traversed again and copy the already calculated A1 sub tree. But I don't know how this is done or how to do it efficiently.

Comment: Your original data layout is your problem because it interleaves trees.  It would be better if you organised your data by Assembled component/component tree.

Comment: It would help if you could show what output you'd like to see.  For example  B2 appears in both trees but there's only one line in the listing, so what should the "level" be for that?

Comment: I edited what the desired output should be. I only care about the highest depth of an item since it will be easier that way to count the total amount of a given item in another script later on. The data is organized in this way and I don't think I can ask them to redo their organization of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```vb
Sub BOM()
    
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim lvl As Long, children As New Collection, child, v
    Dim endRow As String, ws As Worksheet, arr, r As Long, r2 As Long, matched As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C" & ws.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row)
    rng.Columns(3).ClearContents
    arr = rng.Value
    
    lvl = 1
    'collect all the "root" parents
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not Exists(arr(r, 1), arr, 2) Then
            arr(r, 3) = lvl
        End If
    Next r
    
    'match the others...
    Do
        matched = False
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If arr(r, 3) = lvl Then
                v = arr(r, 2)                     'child
                For r2 = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
                    If r2 <> r Then
                        If arr(r2, 1) = v Then    'found as parent?
                            arr(r2, 3) = lvl + 1
                            matched = True
                        End If
                    End If
                Next r2
            End If
        Next r
        If Not matched Then Exit Do 'keep going while had any match...
        lvl = lvl + 1               'next level
    Loop
    
    rng.Value = arr   'restore array
    
End Sub

'Does value `v` exists in column `lookInCol` of 2D array `arr`?
Function Exists(v, arr, lookInCol As Long)
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(r, lookInCol) = v Then
            Exists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

Pic:
[image]

EDIT: child A1 shows up as both level 1 and level 2 - not sure if those both need to be the same value?  If Yes then you'd need to add one more loop to set each child's level to {max of associated levels}.